# Find $f^{(n)}(x)$ if $f(x) = \frac{x^n}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus

> For $f(x) = \frac{x^n}{1-x}$, find $f^{(n)}(x)$.

This is my homework question. We solved a similar problem in class, but of course that was easier. I take the first derivative, and I try to take second ,but it is too complicated.
$$f'(x)=\frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1-x)}-\frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Hint:  write $f(x)=\frac {x^n-1}{1-x}+\frac 1{1-x}$

Comment: I've attempted to format the equations. Please check that the results are as intended. For the future, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^n}{1 - x} = -\frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x} + \frac{1}{1 - x} = -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k + (1 - x)^{-1} $$

and since the $n$-th derivative of $x^0, \dots, x^{n-1}$ is zero we have
$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \left( (1 - x)^{-1} \right)^{(n)} = (-1)^n n! (1 - x)^{-1 - n}.$$